# MantaRay opens 3 TCP connections on the same port

Tags: java, tcp, message-queue, messaging, ip

Another problem with mantaray: We have "a lot" of PCs in a network, our p2p messaging software uses MantaRay (which we plan to replace with something else). On some PCs the task manager shows CPU at 100% when this application runs.

We tried to investigate that with TCPView, and found that these PCs open more than one TCP connection from the **same** client TCP port to the **same** server port.

This problem occurs on relatively slow machines, with Windows XP SP2 (or SP3).

Does anybody know of similar problems? Is there a way to avoid it? Are we doing something wrong?

A first solution was setting *TcpMaxConnectRetransmissions* to 0 in Windows Registry, but I  don't think it's the right solution, and could have other consequences. I think it shouldn't happen, and I see that as a Windows XP bug.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible by the rules of TCP. Netstat is known to produce phantom entries, which might explain it, maybe TCPView is getting its info the same way. It is quite impossible.

Comment: I find it strange too, but we could reproduce it, and when it happens the affected PCs hang (with 100% CPU load).
I have no explanation, and any hint is welcome.

Comment: I think I would reinstall the operating system. It really is impossible. If TCP ever allowed it to happen it would have no way of knowing which of those connections is which.